# WPF XAML изменить цвет Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Не работает увы, как изменить `Background` **Canvas**?

```
<Canvas Background="#FF3D689B" Height="110"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,46,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding _SelectFile}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Canvas.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Style>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: возможно причина в этом свойстве: VerticalAlignment="Top"

Comment: ради интереса попробовал, но нет, не в этом дело.

Comment: Цвет в стиль перенесите (`<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3D689B"/>`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Thx, это помогло, догадывался, что так можно сделать, но не знал как.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, неплохо бы объяснить почему так и дать ссылку на порядок установки значения DP :) [пс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF есть некий [приоритет значения свойств](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence), по которому цвет установленный в виде "локального значения" (`Background="#FF3D689B"`) имеет приоритет выше, чем стиль.

**Список приоритетов:**

1. Приведение системы свойств.
2. Активные анимации или анимации с поведением Hold.
3. Локальное значение.
4. Свойства шаблона TemplatedParent.
5. Неявный стиль.
6. Триггеры стилей.
7. Триггеры шаблонов.
8. Методы задания стилей.
9. Стиль (тема) по умолчанию.
10. Наследование.
11. Значение по умолчанию из метаданных свойства зависимости.

Как видите, локальные значения выше, чем стили и триггеры по приоритету.
Исходя из этого, цвет должен находится в самом стиле, тогда все задуманное вами будет работать.

```
<Canvas ... >
    ...
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3D689B"/> <!-- <<<-- сам цвет -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

---

Из документации:

> За исключением динамических значений и приведения наборы локальных свойств устанавливаются с наивысшим приоритетом. Если значение задается локально, можно ожидать, что значение будет соблюдаться, даже если выше все стили и шаблоны элемента управления. Здесь в примере Background устанавливается в красный цвет локально. Таким образом, стиль, определенный в этой области, несмотря на то, что он является неявным стилем, который в противном случае применяется ко всем элементам этого типа в этой области, не имеет наивысшего приоритета для присвоения свойству Background его значения. Если удалить локальное значение Red из этого экземпляра Button, то стиль получит приоритет и кнопка получит значение Background из стиля. Внутри стиля приоритет получают триггеры, поэтому кнопка будет синей, если указатель мыши находится над ней, и зеленым в других случаях.

---

<sup>Спасибо @Андрей NOP</sup>