# Как корректно изменить стиль кнопки, если она нажата?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-шаблоны

Хотел сделать так, чтобы при нажатой кнопки визуально было понятнее для пользователя, что она нажата. Определил ресурс на уровне окна кодом:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CenterDataGridColumnsHeaders" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="50" ShadowDepth="10"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Но при таком подходе эффект блюра заметен, а фон кнопки не меняется. Если изменяю значение св-ва IsPressed на False, то у кнопок, которые доступны фон меняется, а у тех, которые недоступны применяется блюр. Собственно, вопрос - за счёт смены фона пытаюсь усилить эффект нажатия кнопки, но почему он не меняется?

Comment: Тоже самое что и при нажатии, только изменить true на false

Comment: Не понял) Мне нужно, чтобы менялся фон у кнопки при нажатии на неё, хоть так придать ясность нажатия) Если оставить всё так, как у меня написано, то эффект блюра работает, а фон не меняется.

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1080697/220553)?

Comment: Нет, не дубликат. У меня не используется локальное значение цвета.

Comment: Установите в самом начале стиля (перед `<Style.Triggers>`) цвет, например прозрачный: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>` и посмотрите, будет менять?

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Кнопка сделалась прозрачной и не изменилась после нажатия. @EvgeniyZ

Comment: @Genas, окей, если так не понятно, то я сейчас не поленюсь и покажу как это делал я. Только на гитхабе откопаю свой проект.

Comment: [Buttons.xaml](https://github.com/dev-iCEY/iCEY.Controls/blob/master/src/iCEY.Controls/iCEY.Controls/Themes/Controls/Buttons.xaml) вот вам пример, только там я делал состояния не на триггерах, а на визуальных состояниях.

Comment: Спасибо, за пример. Посмотрел, действительно на визуальных состояниях, как угодно можно настроить. Даже тайминги можно переназначить. Ну, а как же сделать в моём случае на триггерах? Приложение маленькое просто.) @ヒミコ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что стандартный шаблон кнопки имеет свою логику в отношении фона кнопки. Ваше значение просто затирается. Как это исправить? Переопределить шаблон и выпилить из него ненужное. Проще всего нажать в дизайнере XAML на свойство Template и выбрать "Преобразовать в локальное значение". Затем в полученной разметке закомментировать что не нужно (конкретно - триггеры для свойств IsMouseOver и IsPressed). Пример переопределенного шаблона для одной кнопки:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CenterDataGridColumnsHeaders" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="50" ShadowDepth="10"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
                Foreground="Green">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                          Focusable="False" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger> -->
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF838383"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Для всех кнопок окна через стиль:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="620.522" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CenterDataGridColumnsHeaders" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="50" ShadowDepth="10"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                          Focusable="False" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger> -->
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF838383"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="33,10,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Foreground="Green"/>
        <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="33,47,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Foreground="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Не понял вот это - "Проще всего нажать в дизайнере XAML на свойство Template и выбрать "Преобразовать в локальное значение".  Не могу найти это св-во)@MSDN.WhiteKnight

Comment: @Genas по квадратику возле свойства нажать и появится меню: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzfgr.png В зависимости от версии студии может называться по разному, например "Извлечь значение".

Comment: Не мог в св-вах найти Template. Оказывается он у меня он находится в группе св-в "Разное" в самом низу. Думал, что если есть список св-в, то он будет упорядочен по алфавиту, оказывается это не так :) Да, так работает, за что Вам огромное спасибо! Но только для одной кнопки. Скажите, а можно такой трюк для всех кнопок сделать? Или только, как выше предлагали создать пользовательский шаблон для кнопок/и?

Comment: @Genas переопределенный шаблон тоже можно вынести в ресурсы на уровне окна (или всего приложения), тогда он будет применяться ко всем кнопкам. Вместо "Преобразовать в локальное значение" используйте "Преобразовать в новый ресурс". Но да, в данном случае лучшим решением будет просто убрать стиль и перенести всю логику в шаблон.

Comment: Т.е. убрать то, что у меня сейчас в ресурсах определено, сделать "Преобразовать в новый ресурс", выбрать нужный цвет для IsPressed или других триггеров и готово?

Comment: @Genas Я перепутал, там без стиля все равно не обойтись. Добавил в ответ пример как переопределить шаблон на уровне окна.