# Изменить фон ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть кнопка:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnEdit" Margin="8" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Height="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=/Images/edit.svg, AppName = TimeTrees.Desktop}" Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Edit</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton>
```

В коде я пытаюсь менять её фон:

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 222, 89);
            if (btnEdit.IsChecked == true) btnEdit.Background = mySolidColorBrush;
            else btnEdit.Background = null;
        }
```

То есть я хочу, чтобы при нажатой кнопке фон становился вот значением из `rgb`, а когда кнопка была не нажата, то его не было. Но установка цвета не перебивает стиль.

[Как корректно изменить стиль кнопки, если она нажата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1107894/461490)
Я нашел вот такой вариант, но у меня не создается `template`, да и он довольно громоздкий, а с `wpf` я только по сути знакомлюсь, тем более с фронтом. Поэтому прошу помощи, как же все-таки мне его изменить.

Comment: Прочитай про тригеры и шаблоны

Comment: @Pekor я пытаюсь как раз этот шаблон вытянуть, но что-то не получается, и как его вставить уже в написанный код не до конца понимаю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635426/what-is-visual-state-in-wpf-and-anyone-knows-how-to-start-understand-and-use-th визуальные состояния в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому пригодится мой код:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CenterDataGridColumnsHeaders" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="18" ShadowDepth="5" Color="AntiqueWhite"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

```
<ToggleButton Name="btnEdit" Margin="8" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Height="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                          Focusable="False" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Effect">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="#ff0000" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="20"></DropShadowEffect>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF838383"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                        </ToggleButton>
```

Он очень похож на код, из ссылки, на которую я сослался в своем вопросе, но так как я и хотел получить такой результат - выкладываю свой код.

Там еще пару свойств, который мне мне были необходимы, возможно кому то будет также полезно.