# Пытаюсь сделать binding в xaml c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

У меня есть Storyboard и анимация открытия меню, работает так: юзер нажимает на кнопку и подрубается Storyboard, он в свою очередь меняет ширину панель до 240, после юзер захочет закрыть панель и нажмёт на туже кнопку, после чего тот-же Storyboard уменьшит ширину до 40. У сторибоарда есть два значения, на 0 секунде и на 1 секунде, с самого начала я подумал что легче будет поставить два сторибоарда и проблема пропадёт, но нет, есть один минус, если их будет два тогда если юзер захочет закрыть панель до того как она открылась тогда она не поедет назад, а если же поставить binding на эти два сторибоарда тогда это будет намного сложнее чем поставить один сторибоард и сделать ему binding. Ну так вот, получается я хочу сделать к сторибоарду биндинг в c#, когда юзер нажмёт кнопку, программа будет проверять, какая сейчас ширина панели, если 48 тогда вторая точка будет равна 240, если же пользователь уже открывал панель и сейчас он хочет её закрыть, код будет проверять какая ширина панели, если 240 тогда вторая точка будет 48, но есть первая точка о которой я не упоминал. При нажатии на кнопку первая точка будет ставится на текущее значение ширины панели. Сейчас я подумываю о коде такого типа:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="clientZoneStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="client_zone" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{Binding ElementName=client_zone, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="{Binding ElementName=client_zone, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

весь код пишу в blend'е. Xaml, c#, net core 3.1
сразу благодарен за каждый ответ.

Comment: Такое лучше объяснять скринами, примерами, а не кодом и "панель после клика увеличивается". Если вы делаете выдвижное меню, то вы не ту тактику изначально выбрали, ибо размеры, это постоянно двигающиеся внутри объекты, что будет очень не красиво, обычно такое сдвигают за пределы окна (или родителя), например как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119186/220553).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы как-то делаете слишком сложно с анимацией. Вам нужно просто указать `To` (но не `From`!) в анимации «туда», и вообще ничего не указывать в анимации «обратно».

Я попытался набросать в виде контрола, чтобы можно было повторно использовать. Получилось вот что:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.CollapsiblePanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CollapsiblePanel}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <sys:Boolean x:Key="BoolTrue">True</sys:Boolean>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="ExpandablePanelStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="240"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding IsCollapsed,
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            Value="{StaticResource BoolTrue}">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="00:00:01" To="40"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="00:00:01"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Style="{StaticResource ExpandablePanelStyle}">
                <ToggleButton
                    Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsCollapsed,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                    Collapse
                </ToggleButton>
                <!-- здесь будет контент UserControl-а -->
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

В code-behind положите свойство `IsCollapsed`:

```cs
public partial class CollapsiblePanel : UserControl
{
    public CollapsiblePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region dp bool IsCollapsed
    public bool IsCollapsed
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsCollapsedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsCollapsedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCollapsedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsCollapsed", typeof(bool), typeof(CollapsiblePanel));
    #endregion
}
```

Тестируем:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        Title="Test" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:CollapsiblePanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Background="LightGray">Content</TextBlock>
        </local:CollapsiblePanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Получаем вот что:

[image: гамбургер делаете, да?]

Comment: Можно ли использовать MouseLeftButtonUp?

Comment: я хочу чтобы вместо ToggleButton был DockPanel с MouseLeftButtonUp. В DockPanel у меня будет изображение

Comment: Ну, можно. Вам тогда вручную придётся переключать `IsCollapsed`. Или можно застилизовать `ToggleButton`, чтобы там внутри положить `DockPanel`: https://pastebin.com/FweWv0h8. Или просто положить `DockPanel` как контент `ToggleButton`. Вариантов-то море.