# Фикс не скрывающегося Popup в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать меню в программе с помощью которого пользователь мог бы настраивать программу, решил сделать это через `Popup`, но после открытия, если я перемещаюсь между вкладками (alt-tab) в Windows, элемент `Popup` остается открытым на экране монитора и никуда не девается. Как можно пофиксить?

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton 
      x:Name="outgoingToggleButton" 
      Content="Исходящие" 
      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=outgoingPopup}">
</ToggleButton>

<Popup x:Name="outgoingPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=outgoingToggleButton}">
     <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
</Popup>
```

Главное окно программы

[image: Окно]

После alt-tab'a

[image]

Comment: Не очень хороший выбор (ИМХО). Если хотите такой выпадающий список, то есть готовый компонент, зовется [menu](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.11.php), но как по мне тоже не оч хорошее решение (не современное). И тут, я бы на вашем месте сделал бы [выдвижное меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119186/220553) (оно еще зовется "меню-гамбургер"), но это конечно дело вкуса и концепции приложения в целом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, я думал над темой выдвижного меню, но не гуглил из-за того, что не мог придумать как эту модную технологию обозвать. В принципе, пользоваться в таком случае Popup я не буду, но вопрос решить хотелось бы, мало ли, кому понадобится

Comment: Так решение вашего вопроса - `<Menu>`. Я не знаю, как ответить на этот вопрос иначе. Что касается выдвижного меню - тоже непонятно, что именно вы хотите. Как у калькулятора Windows 10? Так это достаточно стили и шаблоны для того же `<MenuItem>` переопределить. Анимация нужна? Сделайте сначала без анимации, потом изучите как ее добавить.

Comment: Проблема на скринах, когда я альт-табаюсь, popup никуда не сворачивается вместе с Window

Comment: А попробуйте поставить `StaysOpen = false`, в теории должно решить данную проблему.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, проблема решена

Comment: Несколько вариантов меню с адекватными стилями есть в https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit у них же есть и DemoApp в релизах для потыкать в контролы. Но если вам нравится material дизайн.