# Всплывающая панель WPF с отслеживанием позиции курсора

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть такой виджет:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.Controls.ControlPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Margin="0,0,30,0"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,30,0"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Этот виджет располагается в главном окне таким образом:

```
<controls:ControlPanel x:Name="controlPanel" Margin="0,0,0,45" Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

Мне нужно реализовать следующий функционал, который должен находиться в классе ControlPanel:

1. Изначально виджет сдвинут вниз на свою высоту, то есть скрыт за пределами окна.
2. Если виджет скрыт и курсор находится на нижней границе окна программы или вышел за его пределы вниз, то нужно показать виджет (плавно сдвинуть вверх на его высоту).
3. Если виджет виден и курсор вышел за пределы виджета вверх, то нужно скрыть виджет (плавно сдвинуть вниз на его высоту).

Как из класса виджета отследить позицию курсора в окне приложения (за пределами виджета), как отследить смещение курсора на нижнюю границу окна и за нее?

Comment: Это делается проще, чем вы думаете. Само "появление" делается [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119186/220553), а вот триггер (курсор в нужной области или нет) делается до безумия просто - прозрачный прямоугольник (`Border` или аналог), растянутый на всю ширину и с высотой 5-10 пунктов, дальше вешаете триггер на `MouseOver` по которому запускаете анимацию появления, все, задача решена.

Comment: То есть мне отслеживать курсор в поле этого прямоугольника, а анимировать StackPanel?

Comment: Вам не надо ничего отслеживать, любой элемент WPF имеет события и свойства по типу "мышь на объекте", "мышь ушла с объекта", "совершен клик" и так далее. Вам достаточно взять что-то, что будет нужную область заполнять собой (прим.: `<Border Background = "Transparent" />`), далее создаете для него стиль, в котором прописываете триггер, который будет запускать анимацию "появления" (в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes) хороший пример). Высчитывать что-то, отслеживать, вам не нужно.